# Concatenación de archivos PDF en un solo archivo

Tags: c#

Me salta un error en la linea marcada donde dice que la direccion de archivo no es valido

```
public string[] GetFiles()
{
    List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

    string pathBase = @"C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos";

    List<string> trasteList = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                        .Select(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                                        .ToList();

    foreach(string traste in trasteList)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, traste);
```

// En esta linea me salta el arror que dice, el nombre del directorio no es valido

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.pdf");
```

// --------------------------------------

```
        List<string> filesNames = files.Select(x=> Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();

        listTemp.AddRange(filesNames);
    }

    return listTemp.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Se supone que `Path.GetFileName()` retorna el nombre y la extension del archivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Habiendo entendido el planteo, en donde no necesitas recuperar los pdf de una carpeta sino armar la ruta podrias evaluar la siguiente implementacion

```
public string[] GetFiles()
{
    List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

    string pathBase = @"C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos";

    List<string> trasteList = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                        .Select(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                                        .ToList();

    foreach(string traste in trasteList)
    {
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", traste);
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, fileName);

        listTemp.Add(fullPath);
    }

    return listTemp.ToArray();
}
```

Basicamente se unio aqui

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", traste);
```

lo que obtienes el grid con la extension pdf

En la siguiente linea

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, fileName);
```

se une ese nombre a la ruta base

Comment: listTemp.AddRange(fullPath); -------------------------------------------------------------> no se puede convertir de 'string' a 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Comment: disculpa olvide cambiar listTemp.Add(fullPath); ahora edito la respuesta